# Specify controller & method to use in anonymous function of a route parameter?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm checking out Laravel. Trying to make use of a wildcard route. The 2nd parameter is an anonymous function. Ideally I'd like to do a little bit of validation to determine if it's a valid wildcard option & then specify the controller & method to use.

```
Route::get('lodging/{entrance}', function($entrance){
    // validate if entrance is 'north','south','east','west'
    // send to controller & specific method
    return "entrance is $entrance";
});
```

Is this an appropriate place to do this?

Or should this validation just be taken care of in the controller and use this format for the route:

```
Route::get('lodging/{entrance}', 'Lodging@chooseEntrance');
```

Comment: This sounds kind of weird. Could you please elaborate on why you would need to route to a different controller method based on the value of the `entrance` route parameter?

Comment: @Bogdan, I have 4 different entrances. I was just trying to find a way to use a wildcard to cut down on the amount of routes I'd have to do. Other sub-directories will have a lot more routes. Each entrance will call a different model method.

Comment: The idea is that if only certain routes are valid, then may as well just let the routes file validate that rather than have the controller do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add simple validation to your route

```
Route::get('lodging/{entrance}', function(){ ... })->where('entrance', 'north|south|east|west');
```

See [Routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

Comment: So that shows how to validate the wildcard. However, it doesn't tell me how to assign a controller & method to use.

Comment: Well, in your code, your anonymous function **is** the controller.

Comment: I do like that method for constraining the route though. I had not looked at that option in the docs.

Comment: Seriously? I'm supposed to put controller logic there? That seems like a terrible idea. Can see that being a pain when it comes time to doing some code maintenance.

Comment: You're right, better assign a real controller, but its a nice feature to hack something together for debugging. By the way, to restrict your routes further than just plain regex, you should take a look into **Middlewares**.

Comment: Middlewares seems cool. Ya I could see using this syntax for quick personal stuff. But I think it'd be a nightmare to introduce into a team project or anything that will grow over time.

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::get('lodging/{entrance}', function($entrance){ 
    $app = app();
      $controller = $app->make('ExampleController');
    if($entrance=="north"){
      return $controller->callAction('index', $parameters = array());
    }else{
      return $controller->callAction2('index', $parameters = array());
    }

})->name('lodging');
```

hope it helps  it helps someone.